# How to open interface builder in Xcode 4?

Tags: ios, xcode4

I am following a book tutorial to create a iPhone application.

But I am stuck at the step where it say click on a certain file .xib I think to open up the interface builder. Can anyone advise me where to ind that file?

Another question is that I notice apple will add my project codes to git repository. I think this is good but how do I use git related commands in xcode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the .xib file is in your project, you should be able to find it in the project explorer (press CMD-1 to open the project explorer if it is not already open); [(example picture)](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/_e5pwU0LJbN8/Tdt-P1y3LXI/AAAAAAAAF_0/k19CrSRymU0/s800/USAMountains07DetailViewControllerProjectExplorer.png)

If it is not in your project, it may be close to the files in your project, so right-click a file in the project explorer, and select "Show in Finder".  You can then hunt around for a .xib file.

If you cannot find it, it is possible that the tutorial wants you to create one, in which case 
CMD-N will open the "create file" dialog, and you can select the appropriate template under "user interface", all of which will create .xib files.

To commit files with git, right-click on files that you wish to commit to the repository, navigate down to "Source Control", and select "Commit Selected Files".  [Here is the official Apple git+xcode reference guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html) which you may find useful.